# After 'contour' operation my image will be upside down

Tags: matlab, image-processing, contour

[image: original binary image]
[image: after contour operation]

My code:

```
IM=imread('aaaa.jpg');
BW=im2bw(IM,graythresh(IM));
imshow(BW);
figure,contour(BW);
```

I do not understand the reason why the image will be upside down after contour operation.
Is there anybody knows the reason?

Comment: The *top* of the image is the *beginning* of the matrix of data, but the *beginning* of the axis is at the *bottom*... `set(gca,'ydir','reverse')` will fix this by flipping the y axis (when using `imshow` MATLAB does this for you but with `contour` it doesn't)

Comment: @RTL I understand the point, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about how a matrix and a plot are indexed:

- In an image, or matrix, the element `(1,1)` is at the top-left (first row, first column);
- In a plot, the origin is at the bottom-left if both x and y are positive.

So there is nothing wrong here; contour just plots the input data as a grid "x,y".
If you want to reverse the y axis, you can use `set(gca,'ydir','reverse')` as RTL suggested.